# sql print duplicate value only one time

Tags: sql-server, distinct

i have a table like the following

```
bill_id       sonvinid  tid date                    brandname
1000109201701   13413   1   2015-10-03 00:00:00.000 QED - TM
1000109201701   13741   1   2015-10-13 00:00:00.000 QED - TM
1000109201702   14258   1   2015-11-05 00:00:00.000 QED - TM
```

now i want to run a query in which bill_id should not repeat, and repeated column with same bill_id should be shown as null

```
bill_id       sonvinid  tid date                    brandname
1000109201701   13413   1   2015-10-03 00:00:00.000 QED - TM
                13741   1   2015-10-13 00:00:00.000 QED - TM
1000109201702   14258   1   2015-11-05 00:00:00.000 QED - TM
```

i know i can't use distinct here

then, what query will be the best to run this type of select command?

Comment: This should be done in the front end, not in your query. You can do it in t-sql using LAG if you really want to do this there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get a result from a query where the first columns do not repeat their value until it changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083861/how-to-get-a-result-from-a-query-where-the-first-columns-do-not-repeat-their-val)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN bill_id ELSE NULL END AS bill_id
     , sonvinid
     , tid
     , date
     , brandname
  FROM
       (   SELECT bill_id
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bill_id ORDER BY date ASC) row_num
                , sonvinid
                , tid
                , date
                , brandname
             FROM table1
       ) a;
```

Anyway I agree with the Sean's comment, that this is supposed to be done on UI side

Comment: upvoted, but you never know how did those get loaded

Comment: @LONG what do you mean?

Comment: Data could either be loaded from the front end or it could be loaded via data tools such as SSIS,etc