# Formatting columns in sql

Tags: sql

How do I format the code to have blanks instead of the managers name each time?

Select Manager, Employee
From Work

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get a result from a query where the first columns do not repeat their value until it changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083861/how-to-get-a-result-from-a-query-where-the-first-columns-do-not-repeat-their-val)

Comment: This is usually handled in the application logic, not the SQL.

Comment: This is not the job of SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this, because this type of processing is not really suitable for relational databases.  Why?  The result set depends entirely on ordering -- and SQL works with unsorted sets.

It is possible. Here is one method:

```
select (case when employee is null then manager end) as manager,
       employee
from ((select distinct manager, NULL as employee from work) union all
      (select manager, employee from work)
     ) me
order by manager, (case when employee is null then 1 else 2 end), employee;
```

However, I advise you to do this in the application layer rather than the database.

Comment: That kinda works. It seems like the managers name still repeats as many times as there are employees. the employee name is blank though. seems like making it union instead of union all fixed it.

Comment: @smattiko . . . I see what you are saying.  That should be `select distinct` in the subquery.